# how to avoid For loop to calculate new varaible by group

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I hope someone here could help me. I am trying to learn R coding for my work.

I am following the growth of plants ( called Ecotype) over the time,  they are Treated with Mock or a bacteria Xcc. I have 2 different experiments (done at different time) and after image processing I get the Area.

I would like to compute Normalized_Area = Area(t1)/Area(t0) for each ecotype, for each treatment for each experiment (Manip) which is the Area at a time divide by the Area of this ecotype at the beginning of the experiment(t0). Each plant have a different Area at time 0 and the different experiments have a different starting time. (example of expected results in Normalized_Area column)

Please find below a piece of my df

```
    # A tibble: 24 x 6
   Manip Traitment Ecotype Date                 Area Normalized_Area
   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>   <dttm>              <dbl>           <dbl>
 1     1 mock      a1-2    2017-12-12 00:00:00 17699            1   
 2     1 mock      a1-2    2017-12-13 00:00:00 24538            1.39
 3     1 mock      a1-2    2017-12-14 00:00:00 27958            1.58
 4     1 xcc       a1-2    2017-12-12 00:00:00 19857            1   
 5     1 xcc       a1-2    2017-12-13 00:00:00 27973            1.41
 6     1 xcc       a1-2    2017-12-14 00:00:00 35875            1.81
 7     2 mock      a1-2    2018-03-20 00:00:00 18177            1   
 8     2 mock      a1-2    2018-03-21 00:00:00 20251            1.11
 9     2 mock      a1-2    2018-03-23 00:00:00 36679            2.02
10     2 xcc       a1-2    2018-03-20 00:00:00 17261            1   
11     2 xcc       a1-2    2018-03-21 00:00:00 18697            1.08
12     2 xcc       a1-2    2018-03-23 00:00:00 35345            2.05
13     1 mock      a1-10   2017-12-12 00:00:00 22853            1   
14     1 mock      a1-10   2017-12-13 00:00:00 34641            1.52
15     1 mock      a1-10   2017-12-14 00:00:00 40311            1.76
16     1 xcc       a1-10   2017-12-12 00:00:00 23754            1   
17     1 xcc       a1-10   2017-12-13 00:00:00 33247            1.40
18     1 xcc       a1-10   2017-12-14 00:00:00 40603            1.71
19     2 mock      a1-10   2018-03-20 00:00:00 28201            1   
20     2 mock      a1-10   2018-03-21 00:00:00 30306            1.07
21     2 mock      a1-10   2018-03-23 00:00:00 49086            1.74
22     2 xcc       a1-10   2018-03-20 00:00:00 27217            1   
23     2 xcc       a1-10   2018-03-21 00:00:00 29844            1.10
24     2 xcc       a1-10   2018-03-23 00:00:00 46540            1.71
```

I wrote a piece of code using For loops, but it raise some errors and I would like to turn it into a more readable code with dplyr

```
date_debut=c("2017-12-12", "2018-03-20") # starting_time
data$Normalized_Area = NA   

for(manips in levels(as.factor(data$Manip))){     # for each manip      
   for(ecoty in levels(as.factor(data$Ecotype))){  # for each ecotype        
       for(traity in levels(as.factor(data$Traitement))){  # for each treatment           
           for( dd in levels(as.factor(date_debut))){    # for each level 
            tmp = subset(data,subset=c(Traitement==traity & Ecotype == ecoty & Manip == manips))  # creation d'un fichier tmp
      
            if(dim(tmp)[1] != 0){                                            
            #tmp = ordered(tmp$date[1:length(tmp$date-1)])
        
            # compute Area mean at D=0 for each Experiment 
          
                if(dd %in% as.character(tmp$Date)!=F){            
              A0 = tmp$Area[as.character(tmp$Date)== dd] # Select  A0 in                  tmp$Area corresponding to dd
              Norm_Area = tmp$Area /A0
              data$Normalized_Area[data$Traitement == traity & data$Ecotype== ecoty & data$Manip == manips] = Norm_Area 
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here the beginning of my new code, but I get stuck

```
gpeData %>% 
    group_by(Traitement, Ecotype, Manip )  %>% 
    mutate_( Normalized_Area = Area / Area[which(Date %in% date_debut)] )
```

Does someone have any idea how to do that? I apologize for the ugly code, but I learned alone.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pictures are neither code nor data unless the topic is image processing. While the code-block is  and the question is very well formed, it would help others help you if the data was actual data (or a representative sample). The goal is to have a reproducible question so folks can make a reproducible answer. Please click on the "r" below your question, then click on "info" and review the guide as well as salient links to see how to properly post data.

Comment: Dear hrbrmstr thank you for your comment. I did a copy/paste of a piece of my csf file without checking the format (sorry for the picture). I hope i did well this time.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close to have to solving the problem yourself.  Here is my solution, I used the `which.min` to find the index of the earliest date from each group, then I used this index value in the calculation.

```
gpeData<-structure(list(Manip = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                  2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                        Traitment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L
                        ), .Label = c("mock", "xcc"), class = "factor"), Ecotype = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a1-10", "a1-2"
                                                                                               ), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1513036800, 1513123200, 
                                                                                                                                        1513209600, 1513036800, 1513123200, 1513209600, 1521504000, 
                                                                                                                                        1521590400, 1521763200, 1521504000, 1521590400, 1521763200, 
                                                                                                                                        1513036800, 1513123200, 1513209600, 1513036800, 1513123200, 
                                                                                                                                        1513209600, 1521504000, 1521590400, 1521763200, 1521504000, 
                                                                                                                                        1521590400, 1521763200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
                        Area = c(17699L, 24538L, 27958L, 19857L, 27973L, 35875L, 
                                 18177L, 20251L, 36679L, 17261L, 18697L, 35345L, 22853L, 34641L, 
                                 40311L, 23754L, 33247L, 40603L, 28201L, 30306L, 49086L, 27217L, 
                                 29844L, 46540L), Normalized_Area = c(1, 1.39, 1.58, 1, 1.41, 
                                                                      1.81, 1, 1.11, 2.02, 1, 1.08, 2.05, 1, 1.52, 1.76, 1, 1.4, 
                                                                      1.71, 1, 1.07, 1.74, 1, 1.1, 1.71)), row.names = c(NA, -24L
                                                                      ), class = "data.frame")


library(dplyr)
ans<-gpeData %>% 
   group_by(Traitment, Ecotype, Manip )  %>% 
   mutate(NormArea=Area[which.min(Date)], Normalized= Area/NormArea)
```

Comment: Dave2e thank for your answer.  Unfortunatly in my hands it do not give a good result

Comment: When i tryed to use it on a bigger dataset it was coorect for the first ecotype but it look like it does the ratio using always the same value (the 1rst one ie 17699). I tryed to post a example ot the out put but i was moderated...

Comment: @Mehdi, See the edit above, the code now saves the normalization area as its own column so that you can see which value is being used.

Comment: Hi Dave2e, i used your comment to wrote that data<-gpeData %>% 
  arrange(Manip,Traitment, Ecotype, Date) %>% 
  group_by(Traitment, Ecotype, Manip )  %>%   mutate(Normalized_Area=Area/Area[which(as.Date(Date)==min(as.Date(Date)))]]  . It is working well now thanks a lot everyone